# ssis xml encoding issue

Tags: xml, web-services, ssis, xsd

I am having an issue which a lot of people seem to be having, using a web service to create an XML file but the problem I have is that the encoding is all wrong and not proper XML:

so it looks like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<string>&lt;!--This file generated by XMLPull tool on 06/28/2012 05:01:21 AM--&gt;
&lt;!--Datasource: Ticket--&gt;
&lt;DATASET&gt;&lt;DATAROW&gt;&lt;TicketDesc&gt;TEST TICKET&lt;/TicketDesc&gt;&lt;/DATAROW&gt;&lt;/DATASET&gt;</string>
```

instead of

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?><!--This file generated by the XMLPull tool on 6/28/2012--><!--Datasource: Ticket--><DATASET><DATAROW TicketDesc="TEST TICKET></DATASET>
```

and the schema used:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsd:schema id="DATASET" xmlns="" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
<xsd:element name="DATASET">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element ref="DATAROW" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="DATAROW">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:appinfo/>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:attribute name="TicketDesc">
            <xsd:simpleType>
                <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                    <xsd:maxLength value="2048"/>
                </xsd:restriction>
            </xsd:simpleType>
        </xsd:attribute>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

So the file seems to come in wrong from the webservice (with html markup?)
how can I change the schema above to match this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?><!--This file generated by the XMLPull tool on 6/28/2012--><!--Datasource: Ticket--><DATASET><DATAROW TicketDesc="TEST TICKET></DATASET>
```

I have tried messing around with XML Task and XPATH in SSIS but the formatting is still wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in the **xml task** you can choose **XSLT operation**, to transform the xml to valid xml

Answer (score 0):

you can use "Script Task" control

and use replace to original character.

```
public void Main()
    {
        // TODO: Add your code here
        Dts.Variables["User::SchoolData"].Value = Dts.Variables["User::SchoolData"].Value.ToString().Replace("&lt;", "<").Replace("&gt;", ">");
        ConnectionManager cm = Dts.Connections["Student.xml"];
        var path = cm.ConnectionString;
        var textToWrite = (string)Dts.Variables["User::SchoolData"].Value;
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, textToWrite);
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
```

For example in this case I store  webservice result to "SchoolData" variable and replace it and then write it to "student.xml"
this is my scenario:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm running into this same issue (a few years later), and I cannot use the suggested method of converting & to &, etc. because some of the text fields being brought over include HTML encoded characters -- and it's impossible to know whether the fields' original text included tags or encoded versions of tags.

However, I've had a lot of success in using the Script Task between the Web Service and Data Flow tasks that uses C#'s HttpUtility.HtmlDecode -> it just doesn't help preserve encoded strings if you're dealing with raw text that might contain those encoded characters.